# How to include a folder of libraries in C?

Tags: c, include, libraries, clion, robotics

I'm trying to include a folder that contains a combination of around 60 .h and .hpp files. This folder contains libraries for programming robots with a [Wallaby](https://www.kipr.org/kiss-institute-for-practical-robotics/hardware-software) (a mini-computer-like device) for Botball competition. `include` is located in the same place as `main.c` (inside `code`). Up until now, this is what my header for including libraries looks like:

```
#include "../code/include/accel.h"
```

Just like `accel.h`, I have 60 other .h and .hpp files inside `include`. So, coming to my question, do I need to type out all the 60 header lines? or is there a way to include the `include` folder.

I'm using Clion for this project, if I can't include the folder itself, does anyone know of a shortcut in Clion to include all the files in `include`.

I was also thinking of using some sort of placeholder for the folder name and only specify the file type. So, for example: `#include "../code/include/(generic placeholder name).h"`. I have no clue if something like this exists.

I would also request you to keep in mind that I'm a beginner to programming, so please keep your answers simple.

This is just for some extra info:
The Wallaby is a mini computer to which you would connect your sensors, motors, servos and cameras in order to control a robot for the Botball competition. Usually, one can connect to the Wallaby either via Wifi Direct or a cable and write programs on it directly through an online interface (not entirely sure of the word for it, but you just type in an IP address in your browser and it brings up an interface where you can make projects and code). All the code written in that interface saves directly onto the Wallaby. Here the default include statement is `#include <kipr/botball.h>`, so I'm assuming that `botball.h` (which is located on the Wallaby's storage) has all those 60 libraries consolidated in it. I got the include folder that I'm using from [GitHub](https://github.com/kipr/libwallaby). This link was provided to me by one of the Botball organisers. So the main point in me trying to download the library is so that I can write and successfully compile code even when I'm not connected to the Wallaby. Hope this provides some relevant context.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Less typing? Faster something? Smaller something? More maintainability? More readability?

Comment: You want a simple and answer (and there is one), but you have written a very complex (or at least long) question with a great deal of irrelevant information.  Your question can be summarised as "How do I add and include folder to my project in CLion?" - nothing more; it is a genefric question and has nothing to do with the specific library.

Comment: I wonder whether there really is a code file which needs all 60 headers. Or the other way round, can anything be designed with 60 headers, all of which are needed by an obvious usecase?

Comment: Hmm. Two readers, two ways of reading your question. Is it "how can inlcude lots of headers?" (my reading) Or is it "how can I get rid of the '../code/include' part of my include instructions?" (the other, I think; @Clifford feel free to correct me)

Comment: Note that header files are not _library files_.  You will have to link the associated library as well I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

CLion is an IDE for Clang and GCC.  These compilers are instructed to search paths for include files by specifying `-I<path>` command line arguments.  Any number may be specified, and they are searched in the order given, and the first match found is the file that gets included.

I am not familiar with CLion specifically but no doubt it has a dialog somewhere where you can set header file search paths.

---

Edit:  It seems that CLion may not make this so straightforward.  I understand that you have to add then via CMake: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html#command:include_directories, but after that, the IDE will not recognise the header in the editor and will warn you of unrecognised files and will not provide code comprehension features.  I believe it will build nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is

Create (maybe with scripting tools or a specific program) a "all.h" file which includes all the other header files

```
#ifndef ALL_INCLUDED
#define ALL_INCLUDED
#include "accel.h"
#include "bccel.h"
//...
#include "zccel.h"
#endif
```

Include "all.h" in your main file

```
#include "../code/include/all.h"
```

You can create "all.h" automatically every time you build your code.